# Gerrit search changes via 'before' statement and got some issue

Tags: gerrit

My Gerrit version is 3.1.2 and my timezone is 
I have a change that created at `2020-05-07 21:27` and merged at `2020-05-07 21:32`. Then I try to search this change.

I search by condition `before: 2020-05-07 23:59:00` and cannot find this change.
I search by condition `before: 2020-05-08 00:01:00` and this change was found.

Is there any idea about this issue or anyway to report this issue to Gerrit?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure no other change was made after the merge? What is the "Updated" field value at the change page? Point your mouse above the time value to see the full date/time.

Comment: Hi, I am sure that the change is existed and the time is correct.

Comment: You don't have answered my second question.

Comment: Hi, I move the mouse over the Update field and see the "2020-05-07 21:32:23 UTC+04:00". Thanks you hint I think I can solve this problem for add "+0400" in query string.

Comment: This is what I was trying to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and share it. According the Gerrit document page: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html

`before:'TIME'/until:'TIME'
Changes modified before the given 'TIME', inclusive. Must be in the format 2006-01-02[ 15:04:05[.890][ -0700]]; omitting the time defaults to 00:00:00 and omitting the timezone defaults to UTC.`

Since the gerrit use the timezone as UTC, I need to add the time as [ -0700]. For example, if my timezone if UTC +4 hour, I need to search as
`before "2020-05-07 21:40:00 +0400"` and this issue will be solved. Please note that the `"` is required.

Thanks